# Problem deploying Django-Mingus with Flup and Cherokee. Strange admin behaviour

Tags: python, django, cherokee, scgi

I have a django-mingus blog running perfectly fine with the integrated development web server of django. It's installed in a virtualenv.

Once deployed using the django app wizard of cherokee 0.99.42 the admin pannel is displaying a strange behaviour. Sometimes all apps are displayed in the admin pannel sometime only a subset of the apps are displayed. It's always the same apps that disapear from the main admin view.

The manage.py runfcgi command is launched through the python interpreter installed in the virtualenv.

Do you have a method to track that kind of problem ? Could it be related to environment variable that are not set correctly ?

EDIT:
Could this be a circular import problem ?

2nd EDIT:
The same problem occur with nginx.
Adding Debug=True to the ./manage.py runfcgi command make the setup stable.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped all tables from the database, upgraded to last version of django-mingus after having deleted some dependencies to get them clean installed and I launched the scgi process using a shell script that activate the virtual environment before.
Now everything seems to be stable.